# Postman GET request not supported on a POST request

Tags: php, laravel, http, request, postman

I have a simple route in Laravel 8 to return some request data. But when I send the request in Postman with POST selected, I get an error of "The GET method is not supported for this route." Keep in mind, I have POST selected in Postman, not GET.

Here is the route:

```
Route::post('post-route', 'UserController@postFunction');
```

Here is is the function being called in UserController:

```
public function postFunction(Request $request) {
    return [
        'id1' => $request->id1,
        'id2' => $request->id2,
    ];
}
```

In Postman I am passing the data as json:

```
{
    'id1': 1234,
    'id2': 4321
}
```

I am simply trying to make sure I am passing the correct data in the request but I am getting this error. Why is it trying to hit a GET request?

Comment: Is there any static url redirect calls in middleware or something?

Comment: There are redirects in my authentication middleware, but only if the user is unauthenticated. In this case I'm passing a user token in the header for authentication so no redirects. Even if i completely remove the middleware the error still occurs.

Comment: Move route out of middleware groups, edit the route and return something from route closure and check whether it works.

Comment: Share a postman image of your call, share the headers too please.

Comment: pls share screenshot of postman call with headers

Answer (score 2):

You can't test your POST, PUT or DELETE routes with Postman because Laravel uses the CSRF middleware protection.

If you really want to use Postman, you need to comment it to disable this middleware temporarly in `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
   'web' => [
       (...)
       //\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
   ],

   (...)
];
```

**But don't forget to enable it again once you want to deploy your project in production!**

If you don't want to disable temporarly the CSRF middleware, you can follow the steps mentioned here https://gist.github.com/ethanstenis/3cc78c1d097680ac7ef0, but it's a little longer.